# Qt Widget with QLineEdit-like background

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm looking to create a custom widget where part of it is a "background" that looks like a QLineEdit (or QProgressBar),

e.g. [image] but without the text.

I've come up with a couple of hacky ways to do this, but neither of them seem like a good solution:

1.

```
QPainter painter(this);

int penwidth = painter.pen().width();
int width = this->width();
int height = this->height() - 20;
QPoint tl(penwidth / 2, penwidth / 2 + 10);
QPoint bl(penwidth / 2, height - penwidth);
QPoint tr(width - penwidth, penwidth / 2);
QPoint br(width - penwidth, height - penwidth);
QRect rect(tl, br);

QStyleOptionFocusRect option;
option.initFrom(this);
option.backgroundColor = palette().color(QPalette::Button);
option.rect = rect;
this->style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ProgressBarGroove, &option, &painter, this);
```

This has the disadvantage of not being fully controllable, especially when inside a layout as I intend it to be

2.

Using a QLineEdit widget but setting it to NoFocus and ReadOnly.

This seems like overkill to me, as I'll never want any of the text functionality

What is the best solution to this?

Comment: So QProgressBar with 0 value and without text is not solution for you?

Comment: To me, that has the same issues as a QLineEdit - a lot of overhead (?) for stuff that i don't want or need

Comment: Ok, what about QLabel with styleshhet with gray(etc) border and white background, label is a very minimal widget

Comment: That sounds better, if it's possible :) I'm already using QLabel for the other (graphical) parts of the widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QLabel` with special `stylesheet`:

```
ui->label->setText("");
ui->label->setStyleSheet("QLabel{ border: 1px solid gray; background-color:white; border-radius:2px}");
```

Stylesheet:

```
QLabel
{
 border: 1px solid gray;
 background-color:white;
 border-radius:2px
}
```

`QLabel` has no any other unnecessary things so it is better than `QLineEdit` or `QProgressBar`.

Result:

[image]